# How best to integrate a search service for multiple microservices with an API gateway

Tags: search, microservices

We have a bunch of microservices with an API gateway in front. We have created a search service that would search across the services and aggregate the data for the client app. We have two approaches to go about it:

1. Let the API gateway contact search service directly, giving it the context about which microservice to search in.
2. Let the API gateway contact each microservice directly (which we are already doing currently), and let each of the microservice handle contacting (or not) the search service by themselves.

I liked the 2nd approach because it would cleanly hide the search abstraction away from the API gateway, but since each microservice is responsible for contacting the search service, there might be search handling logic duplication across the services, which we would want to avoid since the number of services we have is huge.

What would you suggest would be the better pattern to go ahead with? Is there an even better architecture than these that I could leverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the responsibility of the search service, but If, as I imagine, is a service that aggregates information of other services to show to the user I would handle this problem using one of these two approaches:

1. The search service is the one that calls periodically each of the microservices asking for the information that needs and processing it accordingly.
2. If the search service doesn't know when this information will be generated and you want to update it near real time without the cost of doing an intensive polling, I will use a message broker where the different microservices will produce events with the information and the search service will consume them and update its information accordingly

Either way, I wouldn't use the API gateway as an orchestrator to call the different microservices because the API gateway shouldn't know anything about the business logic, its responsibility is only to be a single point of entrance for outside calls and maybe other cross-cutting tasks as audit or authorization

Comment: Actually, our API gateway currently does call different microservices directly (via REST or client APIs).

From what I understood, you suggested the two to architecture a search service, push and pull. Correct me if I'm wrong.
But my question was more about whether the search should sit in between the microservices and the API gateway or should the API gateways themselves talk to the search service directly. (Given that we already have the API gateway directly talking to the microservices).

Comment: I tried to explain that the api gateway should be use to route the calls from the outside to any of your services (including the search service) but it shouldn't start any communication by itself. It must be the search service the one who has to query the other services or the services push its data to a message broker

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks! Does this principle have any name? So that I could research low-level API implementations for such types of architectures.

Comment: You can search for the api gateway pattern